# MODX Revo Не работает форма обратной связи

Tags: modx, smtp

Выдает следующую ошибку:
[FormIt] Произошла ошибка при попытке отправить почту. Ошибка соединения с SMTP-сервером https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Настройки для smtp:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
SMTP-пользователь: info@domain_name.ru
Использовать SMTP: да

Может, кто сталкивался и знает, как решить данную проблему?
Версия MODX 2.6.0-pl

Comment: Попробуйте `SMTP хосты` (mail_smtp_hosts) установить 
`ssl://smtp.mail.ru` а `SMTP префикс для соединений` убрать, у меня так почта яндекса настроена

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло, но спасибо за вариант

Comment: По всей видимости нужно обновить версию PHP на сервере... Должно работать на версии 5.6 и выше...
Спасибо!